# Symbolic Link & LAMPP htdocs

Tags: linux, xampp, symbolic-link, documentroot

I went through these steps in order to make a symlink directory to use outside of lampp htdocs.

```
$ mkdir test
$ chmod 777 test
//test is now in /home/Dropbox/test/
//I put an index.html with 777 perms in it.
$ cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/
$ sudo ln -s /home/Dropbox/test/ /opt/lampp/htdocs/$USER
//my user appears as symlink directory in htdocs.
$ /opt/lampp/lampp stop
$ /opt/lampp/lampp start
//lampp is now restarted
```

I type in localhost/*myusername* and get a 404 error... object not found.

Note that I can create regular directories and .html/.php files in the htdocs directory, but I cannot do any symlink directories or .html/.php files, they will not load.

Thank you for input!

### httpd conf (only the parts involving SymLinks)

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    #XAMPP
    #Order deny,allow
    #Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    # XAMPP
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes


    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    #AllowOverride None
    # since XAMPP 1.4:
    AllowOverride All


    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

### error_log

```
$ tail -f error_log 
[Fri Dec 23 13:55:50 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /opt/lampp/htdocs/*myusername*
[Fri Dec 23 13:56:02 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 23 13:56:08 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /opt/lampp/bin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 23 13:56:08 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Dec 23 13:56:08 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `localhost' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Dec 23 13:56:08 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Dec 23 13:56:08 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Dec 23 13:56:09 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Dec 23 13:56:09 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `localhost' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Dec 23 13:56:09 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0c PHP/5.3.8 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

### access_log

```
$ tail -f access_log 
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2011:13:41:27 -0500] "GET /work HTTP/1.1" 403 1111
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2011:13:41:27 -0500] "GET /work HTTP/1.1" 403 1111
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2011:13:41:28 -0500] "GET /work HTTP/1.1" 403 1111
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2011:13:55:47 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2011:13:55:47 -0500] "GET /xampp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 588
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2011:13:55:47 -0500] "GET /xampp/head.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1362
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2011:13:55:47 -0500] "GET /xampp/navi.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2290
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2011:13:55:47 -0500] "GET /xampp/start.php HTTP/1.1" 200 786
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2011:13:55:47 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 30894
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2011:13:55:50 -0500] "GET /work HTTP/1.1" 403 1111
```

### Permissions of /opt/lampp/htdocs/

drwxr-xr-x  4 nobody root  4096 2011-12-23 13:32 htdocs

### Permissions of /opt/lampp/htdocs/*myusername*

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root    39 2011-12-23 13:12 *myusername*

### Permissions of /home/Dropbox/test/

drwxr-xr-x  2 work work 4096 2011-12-23 13:10 *myusername*

Comment: What are the permissions on /home/Dropbox?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The permissions for Dropbox are drwx------  so it seems the owner is the only user to access it. Should this at least be granted for everyone to read it recursively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would suggest that the FollowSymLinks is is not present within  stanza. Here is an example, taken from [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html):

```
<Directory /usr/local/httpd/htdocs>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Pending verification of apache configuration, (which I think you should paste in), this is the most likely answer.

EDIT: After reading your response to embobo, I went and replicated the problem with my server:

```
[Fri Dec 23 23:03:58 2011] [error] [client 192.168.15.20] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/testsym
```

I suggest the following settings on test's parent

```
chmod go+x /home/Dropbox
```

So that the Dropbox directory can have execute permissions for group and other.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It has this by default:    Options FollowSymLinks - is that wrong?

Comment: That seems correct, depending on how you setup your site. Can you paste your apache configuration as well as the tail output from the access_log and error_log file into your post?

Comment: All the info you requested is posted. It seems "[error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /opt/lampp/htdocs/*myusername*" has something to do with the problem. THanks for the help thus far.

Comment: It looks like that was the problem, but the restart should have fixed it. Thinking about it, it is odd that you would get a 404 message, not a 403 message. Run tail -f on both the access_log and error_log file and then to attempt to access that user again. From there, update the question with what you see from the resulting output.

Comment: No changes have been made so the tail -f information in my post is current. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: Thanks! The chmod worked! I have a feeling that this question will be very useful to the large quantity of people asking about this on other sites with no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm unsure about the default settings for that package - but typically, symlink following is disabled by default in Apache for security reasons.

Add this to your config, in a context that applies to the location where the symlinks reside:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: I posted more information in the post if that helps. Thanks.